# Can Visual Studio access TeamCity symbol server if basic auth is rquired?

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, debug-symbols, symbol-server

I have TeamCity symbol server plugin working and can pull symbols & source from VS2017 as expected as long as I allow guest login in TeamCity and guest has appropriate rights.

However, the required rights are quite permissive (allows downloading source code).  This is a private, commercial team, so I don't want to allow public/guest access.  I'd like it to be authenticated, but can't seem to get VS2017 to prompt for credentials or pass them on the URL configured in VS2017's Debugging>Symbols settings (`https://user:pass@my.teamcity.com`).  The output window always shows "Symbol server authentication failed".

Not sure if it's a limitation of VS or I'm not configuring it properly.  Does anyone know if/how this is possible?

Comment: FYI, this has been reported to MS and is supposedly "under investigation".  If you care about this issue, please up vote at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102981/symbol-server-authentication-failed.html

Comment: Good news!  MS responded to the community post above that the issue has already been fixed in an upcoming VS release.  They don't say which/when, but they seem to be cranking out updates pretty quickly these days, so hopefully not too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed in 15.5.  It's not listed in the release notes as far as I can tell, but a [MS rep commented that it was fixed in 15.5](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102981/symbol-server-authentication-failed.html?childToView=150511#comment-150511), so I gave it a try.

After I installed 15.5, it didn't prompt me for credentials at first.  So I deleted/re-added the symbol server setting and cleaned the symbol cache.  Then on the next run it prompted me for credentials, successfully downloaded the symbols and allowed me to debug the assembly.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** [Looks like it is a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102981/symbol-server-authentication-failed.html). (Thanks @mmchenry for the bug report link.) [According to a comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/116660/view.html) it will be fixed in an upcoming release. In the meantime, the workaround below can be used.

---

I think this might be a new bug in VS 2017. After updating to 15.3, I can't get the authentication prompt to appear. It used to appear regularly. Now, symbol information always fails due to the error you list: `Symbol server authentication failed`.

I have a workaround though. The [`symchk.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symchk) utility in the Windows SDK downloads symbols. With the Win10 SDK, you can find symchk here: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\symchk.exe`

Here's an example of how to use it (powershell):

```
& "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\symchk.exe" `
  "C:\path\to\Your.dll" /r /v /s `
  "srv*c:\symcache*https://my.teamcity.com/app/symbols"
```

This still provides a UI prompt to get credentials, then downloads to the symbol cache, where you can get Visual Studio to load from in the Debug->Symbols options:

[image: Visual Studio Debug Symbols Option Cache]

Comment: Bummer.  At least from your experience it seems like it's supposed to work, so hopefully it will get fixed.  Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: Marking this as answer since it seems there's nothing else to be done unless MS fixes it (see comment under original post)

Comment: Updated VS 2017 to 15.3.4 and it's still not fixed.